# How to make a loop in views.py in django

Tags: python, html, django

I don't want to repeat `Destination` function again and again in separate variables. I tried to make different variables and equaled them to `Destination()` but it didn't work. How to make a loop in it so that I don't have to repeat it?

```
def index(request):
    dest1 = Destination()
    dest1.desc = 'Hello, How are you?'
    dest1.img = '01.jpg'

    dest2 = Destination()
    dest2.desc = 'Hello, HOw are you?'
    dest2.img = '02.jpg'

    dests1 = [dest1, dest2] # that was missing.

    context = {
       'dests1': dests1,
       'dests2': dests2,
}

return render(request, 'index.html',context)
```

Comment: Will anyone answer my question?

Comment: I have added an answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

inside your def index(request) function make a loop upto the number of time you needed Destination() object and save data in a list, from that list you can retrieve data later. You can also make list of images, descriptions to things more easily

```
numberOfDestinationNeeded = 4 # change this number according to your need
destList = []
for i in range(numberOfDestinationNeeded):
    destObj = Destination()
    destObj.desc = "dfsfs"
    destObj.img = '02.jpg'
    destList.append(destObj)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this.

```
no_of_destinations = 4 #Some number.
context = {}
for index in range(1, no_of_destinations+1):
    dest = Destination()
    dest.desc = 'How are you?'
    dest.img = '0{}.jpg'.format(index)
    context['dest{}'.format(index)] = dest

return render(request, 'index.html',context)
```

Comment: Then its a different issue. Check if image is present or not in your static directory.

Comment: Images are present. I have edited my code. I missed something in my code. Check and tell me.